# Testing Window.Location.Pathname testing library + jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test to check if the loan page path is comparators/loans.

But the test doesn't work, because if I change the url, the test still passes. What's wrong here?

```
describe('URL page loans tests', () => {
  it('Should render in the page loans the url path /comparators/loans', () => {
    global.window = Object.create(window)
    const path = '/comparators/loans'
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: {
        pathname: path,
      },
      writable: true,
    })
    expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual(path)
  })
})
```

Comment: Why are you trying to test the `window.location` API? What part of your code is this testing?

Comment: Would need some more details to really help, but if you are trying to verify that the route renders the correct component, then considering rendering your component wrapped in your Router or LocationProvider...the implementation details looks a little different depending on which router library you are using, but testing-library docs have some good examples: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router